# Microsite URL in SMS

Tags: ampscript, microsites, sms

Currently for email, we use a microsite URL so when a customer clicks on the "confirm" link, the ampscript embedded in the landing page that it sends them to can connect to that specific customer and write back their confirmation status to Salesforce. 
I'd like to be able to do the same with SMS, but I can't find a way to shorten the microsite URL because with email, it doesn't generate until they click on the "confirm" button. Is there a way to include a microsite URL (using ampscript) in an SMS that can be shortened to fit the 160 character limit?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use third party APIs to short the Microsite URL in an SMS. You refer this link [shortened URLs](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) and in provided example they have used [bit.ly](http://dev.bitly.com/get_started.html) API and few basic `AmpScript` functions to short the Microsite URL.